# Classification of locally compact topological groups

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Can we give a complete classification of the locally compact, second countable, Hausdorff topological groups?

Comment: In particular countable discrete groups. And so that would imply classification of all (abstract) countable groups which is not possible (see: [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups)). Unless I misunderstand what you mean by "classification" so perhaps you should clarify the term.

Comment: There is something close to a classification: The Gleason-Yamabe theorem, that allows you to express LC groups as limits of Lie group (modulo several technicalities)

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez this is for the particular case of locally compact groups $G$ such that $G/G^\circ$ is compact. Still it's not "close to a classification", one does not even have a classification of simply connected nilpotent Lie groups.

Comment: BTW "there is no classification" has several meanings, more or less informal, but as already mentioned, this would encompass classification of countable discrete groups, which is highly considered as hopeless (and high in complexity in terms of Borel classification). Also there is no reasonable classification for connected Lie groups even if there are many more tools to tackle them. Concerning totally disconnected locally compact groups, although classification seems unreachable, there is a lot of recent progress, see work of Caprace-Monod, Willis, and others.